# Prime attributes of a relation in database

Tags: database, relational-database, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

What are the prime attributes of relation R(A,B,C,D) with following dependencies:

**F={AB->C , C->D , D->A}**

options are:
i) A,B,C
ii) A,B,D
iii) A,B,C,D
iv) B,C,D

According to me answer should be (iii) option but answer is option (ii)
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

The candidate keys for the given set of functional dependencies are `AB`, `BC` and `BD`. Since all the attributes of the relation *R* are come at least once in one of the candidate keys, all of them are prime attributes. The given relation *R* is thus automatically in **3NF**.

Option (iii) is right. The given answer is wrong.